# Integrate WordPress login in a Java based app

Tags: java, wordpress, spring

We have a Java / Spring based web app and would like to use WordPress as our blogging part of the web site. The main issue is probably user authentication, and we would like the Java web app to be the master login control.

Right now I've looked around and it looks like WP is using cookies to check if the user has logged in or not. It is theoretically possible to write some additional code in local WP's Core to have some kind of REST API and Java can call it to login to WP but I've never done it before and haven't seen any good examples.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53503/can-i-programmatically-login-a-user-without-a-password) and [here](https://iandunn.name/programmatically-sign-on-a-wordpress-user/), it might give you some ideas to get you started.